# Periodically print feedback about computation progress to console in Blender

Tags: python, asynchronous, blender

I have to automate a long computation in Blender, and I would like to periodically print the current progress to the python console. I know I have to somehow use an asynchonous function, and I am aware of asyncio. However, even after reading several code snippets, I cannot figure out how to report feedback regularly.

What I am trying to do is this:
I have a list of objects I want to apply a boolean modifier to. With each of the objects handled, I increase a counter. Every 5-ish seconds, I want to print the counter to the console, so the user will know how many objects have been handled, a sort of progress bar, in essence.
However, Blender will still lock up when using asyncio, and I have no idea where or how to fix that.

Here's my code:

```
async def test():
  get_model_a()
  get_model_b()
  build_tower(0)
  split_layer()
  garbage_test()
  async for progress in bool_modifier():
    print ("cutting stone " + str(progress))
  print(str(cut_stones) + " stones cut")
  print("Done")

async def bool_modifier():
  global cut_stones;
  for obj in bpy.data.objects:
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    if "Tower" in obj.name:
      select_object(obj)
      bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='BOOLEAN')
      bpy.context.object.modifiers["Boolean"].object = model_a
      bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(modifier="Boolean")
      cut_stones +=1
    yield cut_stones

cut_stones = None
model_a = None
model_b = None

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
try:
    loop.run_until_complete(test())
finally:
    loop.run_until_complete(loop.shutdown_asyncgens())
    loop.close()
```

All other methods run fast, so I do not need any feedback, but applying the boolean operator can take upwards of an hour. The script does what it is supposed to, aside from providing feedback. I am using Blender version 2.79, so asyncio should be built-in and available.

Comment: Why on earth are you using global variables there? You don't need them, and also they are like an order of magnitude slower than local variables (although this is probably not an issue in your code).

Comment: I still need statistics on how many objects have been handled at a later point, so I keep track in a global variable for easy access.

Comment: I found out I cannot use yield, since Blender 2.79 bundles python 3.5. I have already checked, I need to implement my own iterators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [modal operator](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Operator.html#modal-execution) will continue to run and allow the viewport to be updated while the operator is running.

An operator can use [`report()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Operator.html#bpy.types.Operator.report) to notify it's progress in blender's header, though this is not normally for continuous updates.

You could use a [custom property](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.props.html) to store a progress value and display that in a [panel](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Panel.html).